# Preprocessor debug macro for optional logging

Tags: objective-c, debugging, c-preprocessor

I'd like to code in some pre-processor macros to optionally log some information.  For example in the .h

```
//#define ML_DEBUG(x) (x)  // flip this bit to do the error logging
#define ML_DEBUG(x) (1==1) // flip this bit to silence
```

in the .m I implement like:

```
ML_DEBUG(NSLog(@"Class dealloc: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:object_getClassName(self)]));
```

The code works fine as I have presented it.  However I don't think my "do nothing" case is as light weight as it could be.  I had expected to write:

```
//#define ML_DEBUG(x) (x)  // flip this bit to do the error logging
#define ML_DEBUG(x) (;) // flip this bit to silence
```

Since a lone semicolon is a valid objective-c statement, I expected this would work, but the compiler is telling me:

```
expected expression before ';' token
```

My question is:  did I choose the most lightweight "do nothing" statement, by using `1==1` or is there  a less intensive way to do this.  Or maybe my entire approach to temporary debug logging is wrong-headed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing is an empty definition:

```
#define ML_DEBUG(x)
```

This works for most cases, but it does not work with the ternary operator, e.g.:

```
something ? ML_DEBUG(x) : ML_DEBUG(y);
```

In order to work for this (admittedly contrived) example, you can do this:

```
#define ML_DEBUG(x) ((void)0)
```

It's perfectly valid to cast things to void -- it says to the compiler that you're explicitly ignoring the result of the expression.

It's for this reason that the standard ANSI C macro `assert()` gets turned into `((void)0)` when `NDEBUG` is defined instead of the empty statement.